# HTML CSS: Chat box (Ensure that div takes all the empty space and its scrollable)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I've been trying to make a simple chat box, but I'm stuck with preventing the messages to overflow, so I've tried using `min-height: 0` and added `overflow-y-auto` to make it scrollable, but it's still not working as expected.

My main task is to make a smooth responsive UI in which the messages can automatically shrink or grow and the footer should always stay in the bottom. What am I missing?

I'm using tailwind, so the classes are basically self-explaining of the styles that I've used.

```
<div class="flex flex-col col-span-2 bg-blue-bright w-full h-full p-6">
   <div class="flex flex-col gap-2 justify-between h-full">
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center px-6 py-3.5 w-full bg-purewhite border-2 border-blue rounded-lg">
         <ul class="flex items-center gap-6">
            <li><i class="fa-regular fa-trash text-secondary fa-lg"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-exclamation text-secondary fa-lg"></i></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="flex items-center gap-6">
            <li><i class="fa-regular fa-star text-blue fa-lg"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa-regular fa-ellipsis text-secondary fa-lg"></i></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="messages" class="relative flex flex-col-reverse gap-4 flex-1 mt-auto overflow-y-auto pr-5">
         {% for message in conversation_messages %}
         <li id="{{ message.pk }}" class="flex gap-3 px-2 {% if message.is_author %}justify-end{% else %}justify-start{% endif %}">
            {% if not message.is_author %}
            <img class="object-cover w-10 h-10 rounded-full shadow-sm cursor-pointer" src="{{ message.author_image_url }}">
            {% endif %}
            <div class="flex flex-col gap-1">
               {% if not message.is_author %}
               <p class="text-secondary text-sm font-medium"><b>{{ message.author_full_name }}</b>, {{ message.sent_at_display }}</p>
               {% endif %}
               <div class="message-body">
                  <div data-message-id="{{ message.pk }}" class="message-content relative rounded-2xl bg-purewhite py-3 px-4 max-w-fit {% if message.is_author %}rounded-br-none{% else %}rounded-tl-none{% endif %} {% if message.is_new %}slide-in{% endif %} {% if message.is_author %}ml-auto{% else %}mr-auto{% endif %}">
                     <p class="max-w-md break-words whitespace-pre-wrap font-medium">{{ message.content }}</p>
                     <div class="message-like-icon-wrapper absolute invisible bottom-[-11px] right-[-10px] grid place-items-center w-7 h-7 rounded-full bg-purewhite shadow" style="transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.25s linear;">
                        <i class="message-like-icon fa-regular fa-heart text-heart"></i>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  {% if message.is_author and loop.first %}
                  <p class="text-secondary font-medium text-sm text-right mt-4">{{ message.seen_status_display }}</p>
                  {% endif %}
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         {% endfor %}
         <div class="spinner-backdrop hidden grid place-items-center h-full w-full top-0 absolute">
            <i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin fa-2xl text-blue"></i>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <p class="text-center font-medium text-sm text-secondary mb-3"><i class="fa-regular fa-heart fa-lg mr-1.5"></i>Double tap to like a message</p>
         <form id="chat-form" class="bg-purewhite py-4 px-6 rounded-xl border-2 border-purewhite [&.invalid]:border-error">
            <textarea autocomplete="off" id="message-text-input" class="bg-transparent w-full border-none outline-none resize-none" placeholder="Write your message..."></textarea>
            <div class="flex justify-between items-end mt-2">
               <ul class="flex gap-4 items-center">
                  <li><i class="w-5 fa-regular fa-face-smile fa-lg text-secondary"></i></li>
                  <li><i class="w-5 fa-regular fa-paperclip fa-lg text-secondary"></i></li>
               </ul>
               <button class="form-submit-btn px-7 py-3 rounded-xl bg-blue-disabled cursor-not-allowed text-lg font-semibold text-purewhite [&.valid]:bg-blue [&.valid]:cursor-pointer">Send<i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane ml-1.5"></i></button>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

All the things that I've tried to so far is written at the top:)

Comment: It's difficult to help since you only provided HTML. If you can, try creating a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Two things here, the first one is that I was using ul and li after overflow-y (to the messages itself) and as I've switched to div and set min-height: 0; on "flex flex-col col-span-2 bg-blue-bright w-full h-full p-6" it's now responsive. Maybe can you tell my why?